# how do i increment the label value as each row is created

Tags: php

using a php file to prompt for number of textboxes to dynamically generate which is then sent to another php file that will also ask for input then process it. I haven't gotten that far because I haven't figured out how to increment the text that identifies each text box. Basically I want to generate rows of textboxes based on number selected on another page for coordinates. it should look something like this, however all my rows/cols are (letter)1.

```
(x1: textbox    y1: textbox    z1: textbox
 x2: textbox    y2: textbox    z2: textbox)
```

My code generates each row but how do i update the x, y, z values? Here is my code. I also know that I need error validation and checking against injection. This is only on my local system and I will add those pieces later...constructive comments appreciated. Not everyone quickly grasps all topics. Thanks!

index.php

```
<h2>Choose value <em>n</em>(1 to 20) to enter coordinates</h2>
<!--Create form-->
<form method="post" action="gen_textbox.php">
<label>value <em>n</em></label>
<select name="num_boxes"><!--Option dropdown list-->
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
    <option value="6">6</option>
    <option value="7">7</option>
    <option value="8">8</option>
    <option value="9">9</option>
    <option value="10">10</option>
    <option value="11">11</option>
    <option value="12">12</option>
    <option value="13">13</option>
    <option value="14">14</option>
    <option value="15">15</option>
    <option value="16">16</option>
    <option value="17">17</option>
    <option value="18">18</option>
    <option value="19">19</option>
    <option value="20">20</option>
    </select>
<!--code for submit button-->
    <input type="submit" name="button1" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

second page where first outputs:

### Please enter values for 6 coordinates.

```
<?php
$num_boxes = $_POST['num_boxes'];
for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $num_boxes; $counter++) {
    //echo "$counter<br>\n";
}
?>
<form method="post" action="process_input.php">
<?php for ($counter = 1; $counter <= $num_boxes; $counter++) { ?>
(x1: <input name="text<?php echo $counter; ?>" type="text" value="">,
y1: <input name="text<?php echo $counter; ?>" type="text" value"">,
z1: <input name="text<?php echo $counter; ?>" type="text" value"">)<br><br>
<?php } ?>
<input name="button2" type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Really? is it that easy? I was certain there was a need for a complex nested for loop that I surely wasn't going to understand

Comment: Thanks! I spent the last 4.5 hours looking through my book and the web to find solution. this is first phase and I'm sure to have follow on questions.

Comment: change x1 to x<?php echo $counter;?> and also y1 and z1.

Comment: Genius!! super....and now i learned something new.

Comment: Definitely! thanks again for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a suffix for every field : `x1: <input name="textx<?php` , `y1: <input name="texty<?php` , `z1: <input name="textz<?php` . Do you see it? "textx", "texty", "textz". The result will be "textx1", "textx2", etc, "texty1", "texty2", etc.

Once in PHP code, it might be a little complicated to get those values. Maybe you may change to arrays, example : `x1: <input name="textx[]` (with brackets).